# Matrix $C$ gives rise to bilinear form $g$ ex.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> Generalize the results of the section as follows.
>
> (a) Let $C$ be an $m\times n$ matrix in $K$. Show that $C$ gives rise to a bilinear form $g:K^m\times K^{n}\to K$ by the rule:
>
> $g(X,Y)=X^tCY,\:\:\:\:X\in K^m,Y\in K^n$.

To answer this question I guess I must prove that $g=g_{C}$.

A made use of the following theorem:

> Theorem: Given a bilinear form $g:K^m\times K^{n}\to K$, there exists a uniue matrix C such that $g=g_C$

$g(X,Y)=X^tCY$

We make use of the mapping $C\to g_C$
If we define $X=a_1E_1+...+a_mE^m$ and $Y=b_1U_1+...b_nU^n$

Since g is assumed as bilinear form, then:

$g(X,Y)=g(a_1E_1+...+a_mE^m,b_1U_1+...b_nU^n)\\=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_ib_jg(E_i,U_j)\\=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_ib_jc_{ij}=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}a_ic_{ij}b_j$ by bilinear properties(linearity).

$c_{ij}$ is the matrix $C$.

Therefore $g=g_C$, and the matrix C determines a unique g and g determines a unique matrix $C$.$\blacksquare$

Since $C\to g_C$ is a linear map(already proven in the book and easily deduced by the bilinear from properties). The last mapping is an isomorphism.

Therefore this proves the claim that $C$ gives rise to a bilinear form $g$.

**Questions**:

**1)** Can someone tell me if I interpreted well the question?

**2)** Is the proof right, consistent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as what I have understand from the so called question, you just need to show that $g$ defines a _bilinear map_.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I guess $g$ is already assumed to be a bilinear map. In the previous questions bilinear forms such as $g$ are already proven bilinear. This question 7), that is why I think this question has not that intent.

Comment: You cannot assume that a "thing" with _its definition_ is a _map_ without actually proving it. If $g$ with this definition is proved that it indeed defines a bilinear map, then I don't know what they are asking either, but if it is not the case, I don't see anything to prove or show in such a question.

Comment: @onurcanbektas                     That was already proven in a book example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of claim (a) is simple. It suffices to check the bilinearity of the map $g$, that if that for all $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\mu_1,\mu_2\in K$, $X_1,X_2\in K^m$ and $Y_1,Y_2\in K^n$ holds

$$g(\lambda_1 X_1+\lambda_2 X_2, \mu_1 Y_1+\mu_2 Y_2)=$$
$$\lambda_1\mu_1 g(X_1, Y_1)+ \lambda_1\mu_2 g(X_1, Y_2)+
\lambda_2\mu_1 g(X_2, Y_1)+ \lambda_2\mu_2 g(X_2, Y_2).$$

This follows from the linearity of matrix transposition and multiplication (I’ll assume that $K$ is commutative)

$$(\lambda_1 X_1+\lambda_2 X_2)^tC(\mu_1 Y_1+\mu_2 Y_2)=$$
$$\lambda_1\mu_1X_1^tCY_1+ \lambda_1\mu_2 X_1^tCY_2+
\lambda_2\mu_1 X_2^tCY_1+ \lambda_2\mu_2 X_2^tCY_2.$$

Now, if we take into account Theorem, which I interpret as $g(X,Y)=g_C(X,Y)=X^tCY$  for all $X\in K^m$ and $Y\in K^n$ and some $m\times n$ matrix $C$ over $K$ then we’ll see that bilinear forms $g:K^m\times K^n\to K$ are exactly maps of the form $g(X,Y)= X^tCY$ for some $m\times n$ matrix $C$, and the correspondence $g\mapsto C$ is a bijection.

As we see, the proof of claim (a) does not need Theorem.

> the matrix $C$ determines a unique $g$ and $g$ determines a unique matrix $C$.

This claim is right, because its first part holds by construction in claim (a), and the second by Theorem. But the map $g$ from Theorem a priori is not a map $g$ from claim (a), because the first is given bilinear whereas the second have to be proved to be bilinear. Thus your arguments yield that if $g$ is a bilinear map from Theorem then $g=g_C$ for some matrix $C$, but it does not mean that this $C$ is the same $C$ which is given in claim (a).