# Change in basis leads to change in bilinear matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $K$.Let $g:V\times W\to K$ be a bilinear map, written $g(v,w)=\langle v,w\rangle$. Show that for each pair of bases $\mathscr{B}$ of $V$ and $\mathscr{B}´$ of $W$ we can associate a matrix $C$, such that, if $v\in V$ and $w\in W$, and $X=M_{\mathscr{B}}(v)\:,\:Y=M_{\mathscr{B}}(v)$, then
>
> $g(v,w)=X^{t}CY$

I do not understand this question.

I know that $\langle\mathscr{B}\mathscr{B}´\rangle$ gives rise to the matrix $C$. Therefore changes in the basis will change the matrix $C$.

**Questions:**

**1)** How can I prove that change in basis is reflected in the matrix $C$? Which procedures?

**2)** How can $X=M_{\mathscr{B}}(v)\:,\:Y=M_{\mathscr{B}}(v)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{B}=(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ and $\mathscr{B}’=(w_1,\dots, w_n)$. Let 
$v=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$ and $w=\sum_{j=1}^m \mu_j w_j$. Then I guess that $X=M_{\mathscr{B}}(v)=(\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n)^t$ and 
$Y=M_{\mathscr{B}’}(w)=(\mu_1,\dots, \mu_m)^t$. Using bilinearity of $g$, we obtain $$g(v,w)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_i\mu_j g(v_i,w_j).$$

Thus if we put $C=\|c_{ij}\|=\| g(v_i,w_j)\|$, we obtain $g(u,v)=X^tCY$ .

That is for each pair of bases we can associate such a matrix $C$.
Now assume that we changed the bases $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{B}’$ to bases $\mathscr{B_1}$ and $\mathscr{B_1}’$, respectively. Let 
$$A=[M_{\mathscr{B_1}}(v_1)\dots M_{\mathscr{B_1}}(v_n)]$$ and 
$$B=[M_{\mathscr{B_1}’}(w_1)\dots M_{\mathscr{B_1}’}(w_n)].$$

Then $X'=M_{\mathscr{B_1}}(v)=AM_{\mathscr{B}}(v)=AX$ and 
$Y'=M_{\mathscr{B_1}’}(w)=AM_{\mathscr{B}’}(w)=BY$.

Thus if we put $C’=\|c’_{ij}\|=\| g(v’_i,w’_j)\|$, we obtain 
$g(u,v)=X'^tC'Y'=X^tA^tC’BY$ for all $X^t\in K^n$ and $Y^t\in K^m$, which implies $A^tC’B=C$.

Comment: Thanks! Is your statement enough to actually prove " that for each pair of bases we can associate a matrix C? I would like if you wanted to check this proof of mine on this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371402/matrix-c-gives-rise-to-bilinear-form-g-ex which is extremely related to this question.

Comment: @PedroGomes I added the answer to Question 1).

Comment: I have already accepted it. Thanks a lot!